# How do I make a color-changing background?

Tags: javascript, html

So, I know this may be an easy problem to fix, but anyway...

---

I'm trying to make it where I can change the webpage's background color, in order like below:

```
red > yellow > green > blue > purple > pink > brown > red
```

Click [here](http://www.kahoot.it) for a demo of a webpage that does what I'm trying to do for my webpage.

---

I think I can use some JavaScript on the body element:

```html
<html>
    <body id="body" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
         <script>
             var body = document.getElementById('body'); /* Get
             the element with the id of 'body' */
             
             /* I need some javascript to make the 'hex'
             variable change accordingly, then call the setColor() with
             the parameter as a string for the hex code to change the                                    
             background color */
             
             function setColor(hex) {
                body.setAttribute("bgcolor", hex); /* Set the
                attribute bgcolor to the counter variable */
             }
         </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I just need to make it where the hex variable changes in the order like I stated above. I need a for loop, a while loop, or some loop to repeat the process of changing the background color. The setColor() function is there to easily change the color. Does anyone know how to implement this into a webpage? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use JavaScript to achieve this effect. With CSS animation, you can create your own funky background.

`.background` gets a property called animation with a name (in this case `bg-animation`) which loops (and fades) through all kind of colors. You specify the animation itself within `@keyframes`. The animation time is set to 10 seconds, or `10s` and can be anything.

Read more about `animation` [at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/CSS/animation).

```css
.background {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  animation: bg-animation 10s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bg-animation {
  0% {
    background-color: red;
  }
  15% {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  30% {
    background-color: green;
  }
  45% {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  60% {
    background-color: purple;
  }
  75% {
    background-color: pink;
  }
  90% {
    background-color: brown;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: red;
  }
}

@keyframes bg-animation {
  0% {
    background-color: red;
  }
  15% {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  30% {
    background-color: green;
  }
  45% {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  60% {
    background-color: purple;
  }
  75% {
    background-color: pink;
  }
  90% {
    background-color: brown;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="background"></div>
```

Comment: This method is a little long to write, but it works! Thanks!

Comment: @BenStafford You can simplify it by using a Sass function or Mixin.

Comment: I've never seen such a hypnotizing output on this site %-)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) method, generate color randomly within the callback and update the background. You can provide transition while changing the color using [CSS transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transition) property. The color code can be generated randomly with help of [`Math.random`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random), [`Math.floor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) and [`Number#toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) method.

In case you want to change between an array of color codes then use an array with a counter variable.

```js
setInterval(function() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
}, 2000)
```

```css
body {
  background:red;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 2000ms linear;
  -moz-transition: background-color 2000ms linear;
  -o-transition: background-color 2000ms linear;
  -ms-transition: background-color 2000ms linear;
  transition: background-color 2000ms linear;
}
```

Comment: This would be my approach, using javascript. Setinterval is the way to go, when using javascript.

Comment: This is really weird. When I move my mouse around, the output has a very smooth effect, but when my mouse is still, there is no fade , and it is very not smooth.